# Want to show that a difference equation has solution $y_n = nz^n$ since polynomial has double roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, numerical-methods

The problem statement is: if $\rho(z)=0$ with $z$ a double root, the corresponding difference equation has the solution $y_n = nz^n, \rho(E)y_n = 0, E^my_n=y_{n+m}$.

Here's what I did: Start with the polynomial applied to $y_n$, where the polynomial can be generalized by the following product:
$$\rho(E) = \prod_{i=1}^{i=N}(E-x_i)$$
As the problem statement indicates, $z$ is a double root, so that the polynomial can be written as:
$$\rho(E) = (E-z)^2\prod_{i=1}^{i=N-2}(E-x_i)$$
Let $\tilde{\rho}(E) = \prod_{i=1}^{i=N-2}(E-x_i)$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\rho(E)y_n &= \tilde{\rho}(E)(E-z)^2y_n \\
&= \tilde{\rho}(E)(E^2-2Ez+z^2)y_n \\
&= \tilde{\rho}(E)(E^2y_n-2zEy_n+z^2y_n)
\end{align*}
Inserting $E^my_n = y_{n+m}$ gives the following:
\begin{align*}
\rho(E)y_n &= \tilde{\rho}(E)(y_{n+2}-2zy_{n+1}+z^2y_n)
\end{align*}
Finally, $\tilde{\rho}(E)$ cannot be zero, so it must be the other polynomial. This is where I'm not sure what to do. If I substitute $y_n = nz^n$ I get zero - but is this correct? Or should I solve the polynomial and find the solution to be $y_n$?

Comment: I'd like to solve the polynomial but am having trouble with this. I think the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2-2z\lambda+z^2=0$ which of course leads us to $(\lambda-z)^2=0$, so I don't know if that's helpful. Then the general solution is $y_n = Az^n+Bnz^n$ and I'm trying to figure out what to do so that the $A$ goes away

Comment: There are a couple of things I'm not clear about in your question.  First, if there is a double root *and nothing else* then the polynomial is $(\lambda-z)^2$ as in your comment.  This means the recurrence is $y_{n+2}-2zy_{n+1}+z^2y_n=0$ and things are not too hard.  However if there is a double root *and possibly more* then the polynomial is $(\lambda-z)^2$ times something else as in your question and I think it will be more difficult.  ...continued

Comment: Secondly, in the absence of initial conditions, $y_n = Az^n+Bnz^n$ will always be a solution and there is no possibility of making the $A$ go away.  I suspect the answer to that is that you are supposed to show $y_n=nz^n$ is **a solution**, not **the (complete) solution**.  However that still leaves the first difficulty :)

Comment: Yeah like you said I think we're just trying to show that it is $a$ solution, and I think if there is more to the polynomial that's fine, because it all turns to zero if we have this solution. Thanks for the different perspective!